# Abp Framework AbpUiMultiTenancy Localization

Tags: angular, abp

Is there any ways I can override the AbpUiMulitenancy for localization? Please ask if I need to elaborate the question. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1-) Add a folder named **TenantManagement** (or any name you want) in the **Localization** directory of your `*.Domain.Shared` project.

2-) Create [**en.json**](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/modules/tenant-management/src/Volo.Abp.TenantManagement.Domain.Shared/Volo/Abp/TenantManagement/Localization/Resources/en.json) file (or any other language file) and override the value you want:

- *en.json*

```json
{
  "culture": "en",
  "texts": {
    "Volo.Abp.TenantManagement:DuplicateTenantName": "Tenant name already exist: {Name}",
    "Menu:TenantManagement": "Tenant management",
    "Tenants": "Tenants",
    "NewTenant": "New tenant",
    "TenantName": "Tenant name",
    "DisplayName:TenantName": "Tenant name",
    "TenantDeletionConfirmationMessage": "Tenant '{0}' will be deleted. Do you confirm that?",
    "ConnectionStrings": "Connection Strings",
    "DisplayName:DefaultConnectionString": "Default Connection String",
    "DisplayName:UseSharedDatabase": "Use the Shared Database",
    "Permission:TenantManagement": "Tenant management",
    "Permission:Create": "Create",
    "Permission:Edit": "Edit",
    "Permission:Delete": "Delete",
    "Permission:ManageConnectionStrings": "Manage connection strings",
    "Permission:ManageFeatures": "Manage features",
    "DisplayName:AdminEmailAddress": "Admin Email Address",
    "DisplayName:AdminPassword": "Admin Password"
  }
}
```

3-) Change the code of the **ConfigureServices** method in your domain shared module class:

```cs
Configure<AbpLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    //other configurations

    //add following code
    options.Resources
        .Get<AbpTenantManagementResource>() 
        .AddVirtualJson("/Localization/TenantManagement");
});
```

> Notice, we've mapped the **AbpTenantManagementResource** with the folder that we've created.

---

Then, you will be successfully overridden the localization key.

---

Check the following documentation/articles for more info:

- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Localization
- https://community.abp.io/posts/how-to-override-localization-strings-of-depending-modules-ba1oy03l

Comment: I implemented this but still not working. for example, Im trying to override an error message from TenantBoxService that use ToastService. the error message is "Given tenat is not available". What I did is I tried the method u suggested where I put "AbpUiMultiTenancy::GivenTenantIsNotAvailable" and translated to something like "Test" but it didnt work. Tell me if you need some graphics for better understanding my problem. thanks in advance!